# What are needed <is/are> managers with new ideas and the will to apply them

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, verb-agreement

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum (page 505), the following sentence is grammatical with either "is" or "are" as the verb of the main clause:

> *What are needed **is/are** managers with new ideas and the will to apply them.*

**QUESTION: Would any native speaker actually use "is" over "are" in this particular sentence?**

***Note:*** This is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226438/what-is-are-new-here-is-are) because that question does not deal with the specific construction: What **are** new here **is**...

Comment: 414,568,243 versus 408,354,715.

Comment: *Managers with new ideas **are** what is needed*,  but *what is needed **is** managers with new ideas.* *Managers* is plural, *what is needed* is singular and the subject guides the conjugation.

Comment: @nickson104, Sorry but I'm not asking how YOU would write it. What I'm asking is whether you find the OP's sentence natural.

Comment: @Tim Romano: Where did your numbers come from?

Comment: @TimRomano: Use Google search with discretion and never as testimony.

Comment: @bib: Do you think that CGEL made a mistake when they said the OP's sentence was grammatical?

Comment: No. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @JK2 fair point, deleted the comment, missed the point of the question at the time.

Comment: @bib "Managers with new ideas **are** what **is** needed" sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Kris: As we say, "I pulled those numbers out of my ass". They "answer" the OP's question "how many native speakers..."

Comment: @TimRomano No, They don't answer any question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["What is/are new here is/are ..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226438/what-is-are-new-here-is-are)

Comment: @Tim Romano: At the very least, let me know how you got those numbers, e.g., the exact search phrases and stuff. Only after that can we discuss the validity of your data.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Please see the EDIT. It's not a duplicate. In fact, I've looked at the exact post before I started typing my own question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be *what **is** needed*?

Comment: I would say "What *is* needed ..."

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you're the one who wrote "This question may already have an answer here", please read my first EDIT. After reading it, if you still think that it's a duplicate, then please let me know exactly where in the linked question or answer "an answer" is. Otherwise, please remove the honorable badge "This question may already have an answer here" from my question. Thank you.

Comment: @JK2: Either you're looking at a misprint, or you've misunderstood what CGEL is saying. I can't find the actual text online, but I note [this reference in an ELL comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49702/what-makes-her-laugh-is-or-what-makes-her-laugh-are-plural-or-sing#comment93036_49702) which clearly indicates that what CEGL are saying is ***both*** verbs forms (i.e. - before *and* after ***needed***) can be singular or plural. If your question really is about the "acceptability" of actually ***mixing*** pluralities, I suggest it's Off Topic General Reference, not a duplicate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's you who're mistaken about what CGEL is saying. Apparently, you haven't even looked at CGEL when you blatantly claim that "I" have misunderstood CGEL. How convenient! I don't have the time/space to type all the stuff in CGEL here to prove you wrong, but I'll remind you that the ELL comment you cited say, "...where both singular and plural verbs (in any combination) in both the matrix and the subordinate clauses are acceptable..." Please try to wrap your head around what F.E. might have meant by "in any combination" there before making any false, baseless claim.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh, and please don't forget to remove the honorable badge from my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JK2: You're quite right I didn't read the full text of that comment before linking to it. But I don't understand what you mean by "remove the honorable badge", and I don't see anything in this question that isn't (or *shouldn't have been*) covered by the earlier one, where the OP specifically talks about "different combinations" (of singular/plural for repeated instances of ***to be*** following ***what***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: At the top of my question, there is this notice "This question may already have an answer here", which I mean by "the honorable badge". Aren't you the one who posted that notice up there? If not, never mind. Regarding the earlier question's OP talking about "different combinations", it's not about whether the earlier question touches upon such combinations, but about whether any answer is provided therein regarding the specific combination that I presented in my question. And there's no answer there that I know of. If you find an answer there, why don't you just show it to me?

Comment: @JK2: I don't see that notice. I think maybe it's only shown to *you* as the querent. Currently, I'm one of four users who have closevoted (I don't know if or how many of the other three cited the same "original" as a duplicate). Normally a question will be closed if five people closevote, and *then* we all see that message (crucially, without the word ***may***). But I'm not sure it's even *possible* to close a question with an open bounty.

Comment: ...for the record, I realise not everyone will agree with me on this point, but I tend to think if two questions are essentially about the same thing, but there's a specific point *not* adequately covered by answers to the earlier question, it's better to seek clarification on the original rather than start a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know what native speakers would do, [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20are%20needed%20is%2Cwhat%20are%20needed%20are%2C%20what%20is%20needed%20is%2C%20what%20is%20needed%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20are%20needed%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20is%20needed%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20is%20needed%20are%3B%2Cc0) is always a good start.

Conclusions:

- *what **are** needed **are***: very uncommon
- *what **are** needed **is***: no occurrences at all
- *what **is** needed **is***: very common
- *what **is** needed **are***: uncommon

So "what are needed" is very rarely used, and when it is used it is *exclusively* used with **are** rather than **is**.

This also matches with my personal experience and what feels right to me.

Comment: Buppose it's followed by a plural noun: e.g., *What is needed is more minions?* Then which construction is more common?

Comment: @PeterShor - A good question. I can't answer what's more common (no idea how to research that), but I can let you know what I would use. I believe it hinges on the subject of the sentence, which isn't abundantly unclear in this phrase. I personally think the subject is hidden, and "what is needed is" means "the thing that is needed is", and hence I would tend to use "what is needed is" even if the following noun is plural. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Taking your example, the phrase "what is needed is more minions" means, to me, "the thing that is needed is more minions". i.e. If you have the question "What is needed to increase factory production", and the answer is "More minions", then the phrase "what is needed is more minions" makes grammatical sense. I don't like the phrases "what are needed are more minions" or "what is needed are more minions "- I don't think either is equivalent to "more minions are needed"; because in the latter the subject of the sentence (minions) is plural, whereas in the former it's not.

Comment: But according to CGEL, any of the four combinations in the OP's example sentence is possible, grammatical English. Do you think that they are simply wrong?

Comment: @JK2 - Yes. "What are needed is" does not make grammatical sense to me, and given that there is *no* record of its usage *at all* in ngrams, I find it highly likely the CGEL is wrong.

Comment: (assuming that what you have posted from CGEL is accurate. I've just seen the discussion between you and FumbleFingers, and a link to a comment on another question, which also quotes CGEL, and I can't understand...)

Comment: @AndyT: FumbleFingers hasn't even looked at CGEL and has even misquoted the ELL comment, which I think he has admitted to. I don't understand why you can't understand anything about the ELL comment. As long as you read the comment yourself, you will get it.

Comment: @JK2 - As a native English speaker, I have no idea what a *matrix clause* is, let alone a *predicative complement* or a *plural NP*.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the OP to be asking whether one form is used by more speakers than the other.

Where I come from, most speakers (when talking casually) would not bother to have the verb agree with the plural complement that hasn't even arrived yet; they would use "is":

**For Thursday's luncheon what's needed is maybe five or six of those very long tables and let's say fifty folding chairs.**

Maybe we could use the NSA wiretapping database to document this. It is probably a treasure trove of linguistic data.

Comment: What if you started with "What are needed..." in your example? Oh, and that was my question, you know.

Comment: Thing is, I wouldn't start with "What are" but with "What's".

Comment: @JK2 - to be fair, you made clear in a comment that you were interested in what sounded natural.  To me, "What is needed... " is much more natural than "What are needed...", and this forces the "... **is** managers...".

Comment: In my own idiolect, I do not start declarative sentences with "What are" as in "What are needed are more full-time jobs not more low-paying part-time jobs with erratic schedules that move employee shifts around at the company's whim so that the employee is prevented from finding another part-time job."   I'd say "What's needed is more full-time jobs..."  I think this is also true of the dialect  I speak, when speakers are talking casually, not writing, or not speaking before an audience where they might (might) pay more attention to what they believe to be "proper grammar".

Comment: @JHCL/Tim Romano: So are you saying that the phrase "What are needed" in and of itself, be it followed by "is" or "are", is not natural, albeit grammatical?

Comment: I don't find it comfortable, no. I wouldn't normally use it regardless of how many constituent parts were required for the (singular) solution.

Comment: If "natural" means "sees widespread use in a dialect across social and economic strata" then no, "what are" is not natural in my dialect.

Comment: I would not say "What are needed" is grammatical, I would say it's wrong grammar. You can replace "What" by "that which". Would you say "That which are needed"? Or would you say "That which is needed is ..."?

Comment: @rogermue: How do you know you can replace "What" by "That which"? Where did you come up with this rule?

Comment: @Peter Shor: Some lousy grammars, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

> What are needed is/are managers with new ideas and the will to apply
>   them.

This sounds a bit odd to me. I would use 'what we need is managers with new ideas and the will to apply them'.

If I planned this sentence beforehand  I would use 'what are needed are managers...'. However, at the time of speaking, you usually don't have time to think about these minor rules. I think most natives would use:

'what's needed are managers with ...'

Answer (score 0):

Huddleston & Pullum are right in that the sentence is grammatical with either *is* or *are* as the verb of the main clause.

(*Huddleston & Pullum* <strike>are</strike> **is** right in that the sentence is grammatical with either "is" or "are" as the verb of the main clause.)

From what I've seen, the more common visualization of the context is with "needed" as the focus of the sentence, not "managers." "Managers" here is construed as a (collective) object in the singular. Thus the use of *is*.

However, when we look at it as a reference to individuals (the context is entirely possible – "What I need **are** some real go-getters to get this done in time.") – in which case *are* is the natural choice.

The sentence in question itself can be looked at in either way, so that both would make sense in the appropriate way. Even otherwise, the alternatives are both grammatical as it must be clear by now.

HTH.

Comment: Let me get this straight. In the grammatical "What are needed is managers with new ideas and the will to apply them", the speaker/writer started out thinking of "what" as something plural and started with "What are needed..." and then somehow changed their mind in the middle of the sentence and continued with "is" and decided to construe "managers" as a collective thing. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: No. I am saying what I said in the post -- not sure if connotes otherwise.

Comment: You should use "can be looked at" in place of "can be look at". I am not downvoting it even though I firmly believe  your answer deserves it.